# How to save the live Video and Audio stream to server

Tags: ubuntu, webrtc, recordrtc

I am using RecordRTC library in one of my project to save the video and audio to the server.

What I have done so far is,

1. Deployed the RecordRTC code to my Digitalocean server (https://www.webrtc-experiment.com/RecordRTC/)
2. Able to capture the video, audio and able to upload to the server after stoping the record and click the upload button.

But, what I need is to upload the video, audio while it's streaming without clicking the upload button.

Please let me know if any helpful links or libraries do this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ondataavailable` method with `timeslice`. It will return blobs at every specific seconds and then you can upload that blob to the server and when streaming ends, you merge all the videos at server side.

[Take a reference](https://github.com/muaz-khan/RecordRTC#configuration)